# how to convert hour minute and pm/m to strtotime

Tags: php

I have a time value `04:30` `(h:mts am/pm)` pm. I want to convert this to strtotime

Also I need to  convert back from strtotime to this format `(h:mits am/pm)`

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself - at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$time_string = '04:30 pm';
$time        = strtotime($time_string);

echo 'PHP Time: ' . $time . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Human Time: ' . date('h:i a', $time);
```

Demo here: http://ideone.com/SR58g

Answer (score 0):

read this documentation of php http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php